# How to code the label tag for XHTML

Tags: xhtml

Label tag coding style.

Can I write my label tag like this.

```
<input type="text" name="lname" id="ln" />
<label for="ln">Last Name:</label>
```

Instead of like this.

```
<label for="ln">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="ln" />
```

Comment: The markup would be valid as far as xhtml is concerned. What is your issue?

Comment: Just wondering and wanted to place the label tags text before a checkbox.

Comment: You can even do `<label>Last Name:<input ... /></label>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, although it is bad practice.

UI design conventions place labels before controls (unless those controls are radio buttons or checkboxes)

Comment: Is there css to place the label tags contents before a checkbox?

Comment: While you might be able to reorder it with CSS, you shouldn't because (1) Checkboxes should be before labels, not the other way around and (2) That is better achieved by editing the HTML.